# How can I connect docker node with docker mysql to write a seed ts to mysql in docker build?

Tags: mysql, docker, database-migration

I want to insert a initial data in docker mysql that it generate with a seeder in typescript that I have in a docker but this not work because when docker node try to connect to docker mysql this fail but when i try to run docker mysql only and after i run node command it work.

This is my docker-compose-yml

```
version: "3.1"

services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        volumes:
            - ./mysqlDb:/var/lib/mysql
            - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    adminer:
        image: adminer
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        links:
            - mysql
    node:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: serverJS
        volumes:
            - ./:/usr/app/
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        depends_on:
            - mysql
```

These are the script that i want to run 1 time only before the node express run server

```
    "db:drop": "ts-node node_modules/.bin/typeorm schema:drop",
    "db:create": "ts-node node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:run",
    "db:seed": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm-seeding/dist/cli.js seed"
```

but I only do it if these script run always it start but i want run only in the first run